# How to add a background image to a QWidget without using QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

**Edit:** The problem is not solved yet, I used `@Scheff`s answer as a workaround temporarily.

Is it possible to add an image as a background to a Qt widget application created with QWidget as a base class? I'm not using QMainWindow here at all.

In Qt Creator, you can generate skeleton source code files while creating a new project. If you choose QWidget as a base class, and you try to add an image as a background by changing the widgets style sheet (wither manually or from the design section of the IDE), The image doesn't show up when you build the project. How can I fix this if it's possible?

I create a Qt Resource File, add an image (which is in the source code directory), and set the style sheet, That's it. But if I add a background color with

```
Widget->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("#Widget {background-color: rgb(55,55,55)};"));
```

in **ui_widget.h**, It works fine and shows up after build.

And if I preview the widget from inside Qt Creator, the image appears, but doesn't after building and running.

Here you choose QWidget as a Base class in Qt Creator:

[image: Creating a new project in Qt Creator]

This is main.cpp:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

This is ui_widget.h:

```
#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class Ui_Widget
{ 
public:
    void setupUi(QWidget *Widget)
    {
        if (Widget->objectName().isEmpty())
            Widget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("Widget"));
        Widget->resize(600, 150);

        // I add this line, if I changed the style sheet to a simple background color it shows up with no problem {background-color: rgb(1,1,200)}
        Widget->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("#Widget {background-image: url(:/pic.jpg);}"));

        retranslateUi(Widget);
        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(Widget);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QWidget *Widget)
    {
        Widget->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("Widget", "Widget", nullptr));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class Widget: public Ui_Widget {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

This is widget.h:

```
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};
```

This is widget.cpp:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Widget) { ui->setupUi(this); }

Widget::~Widget() { delete ui; }
```

Sorry for adding the whole generated code but it might be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty certain `QWidget` doesn't support background images.  Try `QFrame` instead.

Comment: @G.M. According to [Qt Style Sheets Reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#background-prop), _plain QWidgets_ should support `background`, and `background-image` is explicitly mentioned. If it doesn't work with `QFrame` as well I would check whether the image has been added to the Qt resources correctly and whether the path is correct.

Comment: @Scheff You're right.  I just read [this bit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qwidget-widget) where it doesn't mention 'image' explicity and assumed the worst :-/.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Scheff I’m sure the path is correct. I forgot to mention that the image appears if I preview the widget from inside Qt Creator before building, after building it doesn’t.

Comment: After having this checked out on my side, I even more believe there is something wrong with your Qt resources. I didn't use Qt creator but wrote everything in Notepad++ (at least, for the 2nd MCVE) and used command line tools for building. Though, I believe it should work in Qt creator as well.

Comment: The problem is not solved yet, but anyway I’m using the same method for QMainWindow and it works with the generated code, but if I just change the base class to Qwidget it doesn’t, I used Scheffs answer as a work around temporarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I tried on my side with my own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

C++ source `testQWidgetBackgroundImage.cc`:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWinMain;
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("Test Background Image");
  qWinMain.resize(640, 480);
  qWinMain.setObjectName("Widget");
  qWinMain.setStyleSheet("#Widget { background-image: url(cat.jpg); }");
  qWinMain.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Build script `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(QWidgetBackgroundImage)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(Qt5Widgets CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

add_executable(testQWidgetBackgroundImage testQWidgetBackgroundImage.cc)

target_link_libraries(testQWidgetBackgroundImage Qt5::Widgets)
```

Output:

[image: snapshot of testQWidgetBackgroundImage.exe]

So, I was able to show a plain `QWidget` with a background image set by a style sheet, at least, in Windows 10 with VS 2017 and Qt 5.13.

This is in accordance with what is documented in [**Qt Style Sheets Reference – background**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#background-prop):

> Shorthand notation for setting the background. Equivalent to specifying background-color, background-image, background-repeat, and/or background-position.
>
> This property is supported by QAbstractItemView subclasses, QAbstractSpinBox subclasses, QCheckBox, QComboBox, QDialog, QFrame, QGroupBox, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QRadioButton, QSplitter, QTextEdit, QToolTip, and plain QWidgets.

**Note:**

I must admit that I don't have any experience concerning the use of Qt resources. Hence, I provided the URL just as `url(cat.jpg)` which results in the attempt to load from a file in the local current working directory (with success as seen in the snapshot above). The prefixing with `:` (e.g. `url(:/cat.jpg)`) would address an entry in the Qt resources instead.

Further readings: [**The Qt Resource System**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

---

After having read the doc. in the above link, I noticed that it's not that complicated to use and modified the above MCVE a bit:

C++ source file `testQWidgetBackgroundImage.cc`

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWinMain;
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("Test Background Image");
  qWinMain.resize(640, 480);
  qWinMain.setObjectName("Widget");
  qWinMain.setStyleSheet("#Widget { background-image: url(:/cat.jpg); }");
  qWinMain.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Effectively, the only change was `url(cat.jpg)` → `url(:/cat.jpg)`.

Qt resource file `testQWidgetBackgroundImage.qrc`:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
  <qresource>
    <file>cat.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Qt project file `testQWidgetBackgroundImage.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQWidgetBackgroundImage.cc

RESOURCES = testQWidgetBackgroundImage.qrc

QT += widgets
```

Built and tested in [**cygwin64**](http://www.cygwin.com):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQWidgetBackgroundImage.pro

$ make && ./testQWidgetBackgroundImage 
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQWidgetBackgroundImage.o testQWidgetBackgroundImage.cc
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/rcc -name testQWidgetBackgroundImage testQWidgetBackgroundImage.qrc -o qrc_testQWidgetBackgroundImage.cpp
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o qrc_testQWidgetBackgroundImage.o qrc_testQWidgetBackgroundImage.cpp
g++  -o testQWidgetBackgroundImage.exe testQWidgetBackgroundImage.o qrc_testQWidgetBackgroundImage.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
Qt Version: 5.9.4
```

Output:

[image: snapshot of ./testQWidgetBackgroundImage]

Comment: Thank you for this, I tried them and both worked with me and solved my problem, but I'm really not sure what may cause this issue on Qt Creator. I'll compare yours with the generated code and see what I'll reach.